# How to solve this Coverity issue called OVERRUN

Tags: c++, windows, coverity

I write a C++ code as below and use Coverity to check it.
Coverity report OVERRUN error of it, as attached picture shown.
But I don't understand what does it mean and how to fix it.
Any hint?

```
wchar_t* GetMainAppPath()
{
    const wchar_t* mainAppName = L"AIScreenshot.exe";
    const wchar_t* agentName = L"AIScreenshotAgent.exe";
    size_t lenOfMainApp = wcsnlen_s(mainAppName, MAX_PATH);
    size_t lenOfAgent = wcsnlen_s(agentName, MAX_PATH);
```

Part of the error message:

> Event overrun-buffer-arg: Overrunning buffer pointed to by
> "mainAppName" of 17 2-byte elements by passing it to a function which
> accesses it at element index 259 (byte offset 519) using argument
> "260ULL".

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`wcsnlen_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcslen)? What does your code mean by the second parameter? What does the documentation say about it?

Comment: Yes, but the strings are null terminated so there is no overrun. This is a false alarm.

Comment: If the argument is _supposed_ to be the allocated size of the wide string, the function should be allowed to search _backwards_. If you pass in the wrong size, that would indeed trigger an overrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't understand what does it mean

It's telling you that the call to [`wcsnlen_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcslen) is reading off the end of your string.

I'm not going to transcribe the error from your *picture of text*, but you can read it for yourself. Your string is actually sixteen wchars (followed by a null wide character).

You told `wcsnlen_s` that you had `PATH_MAX` characters, and just want to know where the null wide character is. But this is false, your string object doesn't have that many characters in the first place.

> ... how to fix it ...

Either stop using a runtime calculation for something you know statically:

```
    const wchar_t mainAppName[] = L"AIScreenshot.exe";

    // remember to subtract 1 for the null wide terminator
    size_t lenOfMainApp = (sizeof(mainAppName)/sizeof(*mainAppName)) - 1;
```

... or do the runtime calculation correctly:

```
    const wchar_t* mainAppName = L"AIScreenshot.exe";

    // you know it's terminated, so there's no need to pass a length anyway
    size_t lenOfMainApp = wcslen(mainAppName);
```

... or if you *really* want to keep the original form (for no benefit whatsoever):

```
    size_t lenOfMainApp = wcsnlen_s(mainAppName,
                                   sizeof mainAppName / sizeof mainAppName[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the hint coming from Coverity is correct. The function you have used is expecting a wchar_t-buffer with the size MAX_PATH. So the function could cause an OVERRUN when it tries to access for instance the index 259.

Comment: Given that the strings are guaranteed to be null-terminated, this is un-possible.'

Comment: That is correct. Seems to be a glitch in Coveritry that they are not checking for a constant as an input-argument.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned the reason for the issue Coverity is reporting, but more generally, there's little point in using a function that needs to search for a null terminator if you can determine the length directly. E.g.:

```cpp
    const wchar_t mainAppName[] = L"AIScreenshot.exe";
    const wchar_t agentName[] = L"AIScreenshotAgent.exe";
    const size_t lenOfMainApp = sizeof(mainAppName) / sizeof(wchar_t) - 1;
    const size_t lenOfAgent = sizeof(agentName) / sizeof(wchar_t) - 1;
```